# What are some reputable databases for the measured values of the physical properties of materials?

Tags: resource-recommendations, material-science

I am looking for a trustworthy source for the measured physical properties of materials. For example I may want to find the thermal conductivity, resistivity, density etc of Gold.

I don't know where to find such a database so I beseech thee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics is the "industry standard" and should be appropriate for most layman purposes including those listed. Some knowledge of basic physics is assumed. Google Books has a recent edition for free download, any well stocked library is likely to have a print version, and although a new edition costs about $200, roughly yearly editions for the last hundred years means finding a recent used copy at a deep discount is easy.

You may also have some success with Wolfram Alpha, a searchable internet database and calculation engine.